# Stopping Post to external service looking for User ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not really sure how to describe this issue so will try to be clear.

We have a page in our Rails application where our customers can update their credit card details. The form posts to an external service to verify the details. Then redirects back to us transparently.

Initially I had the form in it's own controller for testing (working perfectly) but I've just moved it within my users_controller.

The form posts and redirects to a confirm action which does some checks. When I post from within the users controller, I get an error:

```
 Couldn't find User with id=k2hx5p36w3g9rxsz
```

Which in fact is the id of the transaction. Not the user.

The url looks like this:

```
 http://localhost:8080/settings/confirm?http_status=200&id=k2hx5p36w3g9rxsz&kind=update_payment_method&hash=9c85b12c1242cd58de27b2582c934e34a0e9455e6
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
def billing
  @user = current_user 
  @credit_card = current_user.default_credit_card  
  @tr_data = CreditCard::TransparentRedirect.update_credit_card_data(:redirect_url => confirm_credit_card_info_url, :payment_method_token => @credit_card.token)
  ...
end

def credit_card_confirm
  @user = current_user 
  @result = CreditCard::TransparentRedirect.confirm(request.query_string)

  if @result.success?
    redirect_to user_billing_path, :notice => "Credit card updated"
  else
    render :action => "billing"
  end
end
```

And in my routes:

```
match '/settings/confirm' => 'users#credit_card_confirm', :as => :confirm_credit_card_info
```

What can I do to avoid it taking the ID as the User ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have something like a `before_filter` or `cancan` which takes the id from params and tries to load the corresponding object. This is a common practice in controllers.

The point is that `params` contains a merge of:

- the named params that are set from the router (`/users/:id`)
- the query string, as converted by http://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Utils/parse_nested_query
- the body if present, as above or converted from JSON/XML as needed.

So `GET /users/1` and `GET /users?id=1` have the same effect.

The solution is to understand in which specific piece of your code the id is used to load a User. If it is your code (or otherwise skippable), then skip the filter or whatever appropriate for the `credit_card_confirm` action, if it is not your code, you have to use a separate controller.

Comment: That's got it. Used a load_and_authorize_resource and skip_authorize_resource to stop validation. Cheers. S